# Hyperlink of the protected pdf created from aspose are disabled in firefox

Tags: c#, firefox, cross-browser, password-protection, aspose.pdf

I am creating a password protected pdf which has hyperlinks. The hyperlinks are disabled in firefox  browser whereas it works in other browsers, Adobe pdf reader.

Why the hyperlinks are disabled in firefox for password protected pdf which is created from aspose but works in other browsers like chrome, edge?
[![pdf][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orfUn.png
I have used the LinkAnnotation class to create the hyperlinks in pdf.

```
LinkAnnotation link = new LinkAnnotation(pageno, textFragment.Rectangle);
link.Action = new GoToURIAction("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Comment: Please can you clarify exactly what the question is?

Comment: Could you please create an inquiry over Aspose.PDF official support forum along with a complete sample code snippet that you are using to protect the PDF with Password? We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I work as a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.